# bash executing a function on vector elements

Tags: python, bash, vector

I have a bash script that generates a vector of running Jobs on a cluster. Example:

```
Vector = [1.cluster 2.cluster 3.cluster]
```

I need to update this script to keep record of this Jobs. Normally I would do:

```
qstat jobnumber.cluster
```

My background is python and in python I could do something like:

```
map(qstat, Vector)
```

and this would return me a vector with the function return value for all vector entries. So the question is: Can I apply a function to a vector in bash and get a vector back?

Comment: Are you assigning this via `Vector=(1.cluster 2.cluster 3.cluster)` or `Vector=1.cluster 2.cluster 3.cluster`? Put another way, does `echo ${Vector[0]}` print `1.cluster` or `1.cluster 2.cluster 3.cluster`?

Comment: The Vector is created by appending other commands output: Job+=$Command)

Comment: So `$Command` is another array variable? PS, your first line is neither valid Python (where you need commas between `list` members) or bash (where you put arrays in parens, not brackets, and can't have extra spaces). And neither one has anything called "vector". You'll get better answers if you use the right terminology and actual working code instead of something kinda similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the bash equivalent of the Pythonic code `result = [qstat(cluster) for cluster in Vector]`.

If you're using a bash array:

```
result=() # or declare -a result
for cluster in ${Vector[@]}; do
  result=("${result[@]}" "$(qstat $cluster)") # or result+=($(qstat $cluster))
done
```

The difference between the two ways of appending to the array are that the first explicitly expands the array to add a new element, while the second creates a new array with the new element to add it to the end. That's because bash doesn't have an equivalent to Python's `extend` method.

If you're using an IFS-separated string:

```
result=""
for cluster in $Vector; do
  result="${result} $(qstat cluster)"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

No, Bash does not have a `map` function to apply a function to each element in an array, giving you an array back. You can do this by hand with a `for` loop:

```
declare -a results
for job in "${jobs[@]}"
do
    results+=($(qstat $job))
done
```